# How to use SQL Variables inside a query ( SQL Server )?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I have written the following SQL Stored Procedure, and it keeps giving me the error at 
`@pid = SELECT MAX(...` The whole procedure is:

```
Alter PROCEDURE insert_partyco
@pname varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pid varchar(200);

    @pid = SELECT MAX(party_id)+1 FROM PARTY;
    INSERT INTO party(party_id, name) VALUES(@pid, @pname)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as PARTY_ID
END
GO
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: As @jyparask has said - you can make the `id` column auto-increment, though I'm not sure why you've declared `pid` as a varchar when it appears to be an int value...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Alter PROCEDURE insert_partyco
@pname varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pid varchar(200);

    SELECT @pid = MAX(party_id)+1 FROM PARTY;
    INSERT INTO party(party_id, name) VALUES(@pid, @pname)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as PARTY_ID
END
```

This has an advantage over `SET` with `SELECT` in that you can select expressions in multiple variables in one statement:

```
SELECT @var1 = exp1, @var2 = expr2 ... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @total int

select @total = count(*) from news;

select * from news where newsid = @total+2

//**news** table name and **newsid** column name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SET.

```
Alter PROCEDURE insert_partyco
@pname varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pid varchar(200);

    SET @pid = (SELECT MAX(party_id)+1 FROM PARTY);
    INSERT INTO party(party_id, name) VALUES(@pid, @pname)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as PARTY_ID
END
GO
```

Alternatively, in your case you could make party_id an autoincremented value, so you wouldn't need to query the table.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `SELECT @variable = <expression>` as you can then select multiple results into multiple variables in a single statement

Comment: Yes, i know, it is just the closer to his try.

Comment: @Jyparask! in the alternative case, as you suggested, wouldn't it effect if we want to insert the value by ourserlves somewhere else?

Comment: @KamranAhmed Since you are selecting `SCOPE_IDENTITY` you will get the newly inserted id.